# Get route is not working in laravel when i hit get route using api its return nothing

Tags: laravel, api

when I hit get route it returns this.I tried to get routes by using this API laravel

[image: when I hit get route it returns this.I tried to get routes by using this API laravel]

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth:admins']], function() {
            // Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
                Route::post('details', [PassportAuthController::class, 'details']);
                
    // get all list of
    Route::apiResource('/admins', AdminController::class);

    // opening hours
    Route::apiResource('openinghours', OpeningHourController::class);

    // orders
    Route::apiResource('admin-orders', AdminOrderController::class);


    // Categories
    Route::apiResource('admin-categories', AdminCategoryController::class);

    Route::post('add-push-token', [PushTokenAdminController::class, 'store']);

    // sizegroups
    Route::apiResource('size-groups', AdminSizeGroupController::class);
    // sizegroups
    Route::apiResource('size-groups.size', SizeController::class);

    // products
    Route::apiResource('admin-products', AdminProductController::class);

    // accessories
    Route::apiResource('admin-accessory', AdminAccessoryController::class);
    Route::post('product-accessory-update', [AdminAccessoryController::class, 'productAccessoryUpdate']);

    // products accessories
    Route::apiResource('admin-product-accessory', AdminProductAccessoryController::class);

    // Route::get('me', [AdminController::class, 'admin']);
    Route::get('me', [PassportAuthController::class, 'details']);


    Route::post('category-image-upload',  [AdminCategoryController::class, 'uploadImage'])->name('category.image.upload.post');
    Route::post('category-image-delete',  [AdminCategoryController::class, 'deleteImage'])->name('category.image.delete');

    // Route::post('product-image-upload',  [AdminProductController::class, 'uploadImage'])->name('product.image.upload.post');
    Route::post('product-image-delete',  [AdminProductController::class, 'deleteImage'])->name('product.image.delete');
    
    // sending push notifciatin sued for testing
    Route::post('sendPushNotification', [PushNotificationController::class, 'send']);

});
```

Comment: `/admin/details` is a post route, you are using a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

You define post mathod and postman call get method.

use match and any method you can access post and get method

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', function () {
    //
});

Route::any('/', function () {
    //
});
```